Why does Webflux WebSocketHandler returned as a lambda expression share the response, but not when defined as a component
The following configuration that returns WebSocket#handle as a lambda expression shares the Entity to all browser connections.

 @Bean
        public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler (ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                ProfileCreatedEventListener eventListener) {            
            
            Flux<ProfileCreatedEvent> flux = Flux.create(eventListener).share();
            
            return session -> {
                
                Flux<WebSocketMessage> messageFlux = flux.map(evt -> {
                    
                    try {
                        
                        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(evt.getSource());
                        
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);                      
                    }
                    
                })                  
                .map(str -> {
                    
                    return session.textMessage(str); //returns WebSocketMessage
                });
                
                return session.send(messageFlux);
            } ; //end WebSocket#handle
            
        } //end @Bean webSocketHandler


When I code exactly the same WebSocketHandler#handle method within a component that implements WebSocketHandler only the browser that connects first receives the Json entity. What is the difference?
 @Configuration

                @Bean
                @Autowired
        public HandlerMapping handlerMapping(MyWebSocketHandler wsh) {
            
            Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
            
            map.put("/ws/profiles", wsh);
            
            int order = 10; // after ProfileEndpointConfiguration           
            
            return new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(map, order);
        } 

@Component
public class MyWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

        @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {        
        
        Flux<ProfileCreatedEvent> fluxEvent = Flux.create(listener).share();
        
        Flux<WebSocketMessage> messageFlux = fluxEvent.map (
                
                     evt -> {                
                       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
                       String json = null;                  
                try {                       
                  json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(evt.getSource());                          
                } catch(IOException e) {                        
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);                      
                }
                    return json;
                })                      
               .map(str -> session.textMessage(str));
        
        return session.send(messageFlux);       
        
    } //end handle  
}

General Architecture:
A Json entity is uploaded to a RouterFunction. The Router is bound to a handler
that invokes  ReactiveCrudRepository#save through a Service component. At Service#create
the inserted entity is published.
//Model
public class Profile {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String email;
}

public interface ProfileRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Profile, String> {}

//Service Component
 public ProfileService(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher, ProfileRepository profileRepository) {. . .}

 public Mono<Profile> create(String email){
       return profileRepository.save( new Profile(null, email) )
               .doOnSuccess( profile -> publisher.publishEvent( new ProfileCreatedEvent( profile) ) );
   }

public class ProfileCreatedEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    public ProfileCreatedEvent(Profile source) {        
        super( source );            
    }
}

//Handler

 public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request){
        final Flux<Profile> profileFlux = request.bodyToFlux( Profile.class )
                .flatMap( p -> profileService.create( p.getEmail() ) );
        return defaultWriteResponse( profileFlux );
    }

//Note: The body is not returned in the ServerResponse, so that Profile entity can be published.

  private static Mono<ServerResponse> defaultWriteResponse(Publisher<Profile> profiles) {
        return Mono
                .from(profiles)
                .flatMap(p -> ServerResponse
                        .created( URI.create( "/profiles/" + p.getId()))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build()
                );
    }

onApplicationEvent is coded on a component that
implements ApplicationListener and Consumer<FluxSink>.
The component is used as a Consumer for Flux#create.
Within the WebSocketHandler:
Flux fluxEvent = Flux.create(listener).share();
Flux#create(Consumer <FluxSink>) is used to return a Flux. When the Profile entity is published, Sink#next
passes the Profile entity to React's Subscriber.
@Component
public class ProfileCreatedEventListener implements ApplicationListener <ProfileCreatedEvent>, 
       Consumer <FluxSink<ProfileCreatedEvent>> {

 @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ProfileCreatedEvent event) {     
        this.queue.offer(event);        
    }

  @Override
    public void accept(FluxSink<ProfileCreatedEvent> sink) {
        
    this.executor.execute(() -> {                   
        while(true) {                       
                  try {                         
               ProfileCreatedEvent event = que.take()
                   sink.next(event) ;
            
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        
                }//end while
         } //end lambda
      ) ; //end execute     
    } //end accept
}//end class


Configurations are tested using curl to upload an entity the router. A simple HTML view includes the JavaScript.WebSocket#onMessage defines a callback that displays the Json text.
The code that works was obtained from the tutorial: Build Reactive APIs with Spring WebFlux by Matt Raible
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/24/reactive-apis-with-spring-webflux   
